# What can Neo4j do that ArangoDB can't?

Tags: nosql, neo4j, graph

I'm in the process of choosing a database for a project related to biology and medicine. The main added value of a graph database will be the ability to explore and weight the relationship between different concepts according different insights such as available studies and open data.

ArangoDB provide an interesting but partisan literature about what they can do that Neo4j can't, as well as a benchmark.

https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/arangodb-vs-neo4j/

https://www.arangodb.com/2018/02/nosql-performance-benchmark-2018-mongodb-postgresql-orientdb-neo4j-arangodb/

Ok... Now I'm trying to get what Neo4j can do but ArangoDB can't. Afterwards, they are the market leader for graph databases.

In the documentation Neo4j provide a few information about graph algorithms. Is it something that is only available for Neo4j? Also, I have seen that Neo4j provide a mechanisms to weight edges.

What could be actual example of strong diffenciators that could make me choose Neo4j instead of ArangoDB?

Comment: There's also [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=orientdb), about which I've heard good things (but know next to nothing about). And [this](https://github.com/bitnine-oss/agensgraph) which seems very interesting (again, know nothing).  There's also the unfortunately named Apache [Tinkerpop](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) and the Gremlin programming language. So, loads of choices and no definitive answers. Sounds like, err..., the database eco-system (think MySQL vs. PostgreSQL, Oracle vs. MS SQL Server &c... generally so! :-)

Comment: Neo4j has been around longer than Arango and specializes in graph functionality. As such, it has more graph specific functionality built-in. (algorithms) or available through the community. As such if you really are going deep into graphs, then it may be  a great option. On the other hand, Arango's strength is the multi-model approach that allows it to perform really well and have functionality relating to both document and graph DBs. However, they do not have quite as much depth in graphs (but they are continuing to improve rapidly).